# How do I read an image via http then PUT it into another endpoint via streams?

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I found examples of how to write to local file disks, but couldn't find an example of writing it into cloud storage via HTTP PUT. How can I achieve this? how does HTTP know if it's a stream or not? can any HTTP endpoint support streams?

```
fetch("https://cdn-wp.thesportsrush.com/2020/10/9ad1319a-maxresdefault-15.jpg")
  .then(res => res.body.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./tmp.txt")))
```